# Down-voting as a form of harassment?

Tags: discussion

I think there may be an individual who reflexively down-votes more or less every question I post. It doesn't seem to matter what the content is.

If there is an individual engaging in this sort of behaviour, is that considered a form of harassment on C SE? Do mods look out for this kind of behaviour?

Comment: As moderators, we can not see or have knowledge of who down votes. You can always ask Community Moderators to look into it, but we can not do anything.

Comment: I'd like to think we don't need cops - we have prayer, that's what the NT is about. While that might sound simplistic, we are confronted by the disconnect between the NT and the reality we contend with - a fractured, lethargic, confused church unable to do much about it. It's a discussion well worth having !

Comment: @KenGraham I'm surprised you guys don't have any more info than we do. Then I suppose the question is "Do you know if a Community Moderator would consider it a form of harassment? Would they do something if there was that form of behaviour?"

Comment: @KenGraham We can see total votes, but not in time, just a total count.

Answer (score 4):

Votes based on who a person is rather than the content of the post are not appropriate, and downvotes like that are harassment.

But, it's hard to distinguish legitimate votes from illegitimate ones. The system will automatically flag a lot of votes given from someone to someone else in a shortish time, but it doesn't detect lots of votes that are paced out over time.

The mods can see some voting trends, which really don't reveal very much, and we definitely can't identify who downvotes a particular post. What I can see shows that there's no one who's exclusively downvoting your posts (everyone who has downvoted you also upvotes you), and there's no one who's downvoted all your questions.

This will be a disappointing answer, as all unexplained downvotes are. The only other thing I can say is that I personally think you ask good and fair questions and you're a valued member of this community.

Comment: There are no down-votes at all on these two recent questions [Receiving Comunion](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/91273/if-someone-is-barred-from-receiving-communion-by-their-own-bishop-what-are-the) and [Jewish Marriage](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/91272/what-are-the-arguments-for-believing-jewish-men-would-marry-temple-virgins-who-h) so there seems to be no established pattern.

Comment: There is an established pattern - not necessarily per-user, but for pro-Trinitarian/traditional Q's & A's. My twin Q's about Jesus' dual nature for eg. The Q *for* got 6 UV 0 DV and the Q *against* got 2 DV and 3 UV. Simply *asking* from a non-traditional aspect is punished and the Q often closed as off-topic or something. While one would not expect to get a *warm welcome* for asking (apparently) adversarial Q's, the punitive response seems to be worse than it was and the vigorous UVing of poor quality answers that conform to tradition is also rampant.

Answer (score 2):

This probably won't help, but this is the internet. There are trolls and disagreeable people every where. Not everyone will like what you have to say and some users may dislike the beliefs of specific users. Given a chance at anonymity they may take that chance to attempt to discredit what you say (answer or question) with a vote. Some votes may be like this, some may be legitimate, in which case I'd hope there is a comment indicating reason so the post can be improved. You can't please everyone. Do your best to follow the site guidelines and I believe the majority of users, who do vote, will do so positively.

I would say its harassment if it can be proven, which I don't think it can easily. Votes don't hold a tangible value, and upvotes aren't necessarily support, just that a user thinks its a good post.

Comment: +1 "Votes don't hold a tangible value" Well, they do though. It's a major form of currency on the site.

Comment: "this is the internet" Ya, but it's also a community run by volunteers, who put significant time into questions and answers. I've learned (also see curiousdanii's answer) that there already are mechanisms in place in the site to reverse serial down-voting, which is good to know.

Comment: Currency that doesn't do much beyond slowly over years getting more privilege...is that currency or a hook to keep users coming back. It does show a portion of the effort users have put in, but there isn't much you can do with it. Internet communities all (that I have seen) face the same problem, some people say/do things they wouldn't in person. As long as there isn't verbal harassment, there isn't much to do beyond doing your best.

Comment: Sure, you can give all your score away as bounties. Why not, if it isn't important? Would make a new user's day.